# Linear independence in integral group rings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Let us denote by $\mathbb{Z}G$ the integral group ring of a group $G$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers. Assume that $$0=(a+b+c+d)-(e+f+g+h)$$ in which $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ belong to $G$. Then, $0$ is a linear combination of elements of $G$, and thus $a$ is one of the elements in the set $\{e,f,g,h\}$.

It is right? I think that the elements with positive coefficients should appear also with negative coefficients, for otherwise, they cannot disappear in the expression. Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: yep, this looks correct

Comment: This is correct since the elements of $G$ form a *basis* of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ (in particular, a free family).

Comment: Thank you so much @CaptainLamma. I understand and make sure such an argument.

Comment: Thanks, @Exodd.